# pure javascript client for mongo on node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a javascript only mongo client?

the node mongo driver is native, right? I can see kerberos being compiled on install. plus some places it is called "native mongo node.js client".

[this page](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/) says the following

> It is written in pure JavaScript and provides a native asynchronous Node.js interface to MongoDB

but that just means it has compiled dependencies, right?

it is all very confusing.

I am looking for a mongo client that does not require any kind of compilation for nodejs. does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top end of the driver is javascript, the speed critical parts are native, or it was easier to include an established/proven package like kerberos. Note that easier does not imply lazy - it implies that no implementor has yet thought the effort justified the benefit.

Drivers are listed [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) and it is interesting to note that there are not even minor projects that attempt to write a javascript only solution - as one might see in, say, Java.

Many more complex/mature node packages require compiled dependencies; building node products for the target platform is standard and services like [Travis](https://travis-ci.org) make this easy.

Comment: so, just to make it clear, your answer is "no", correct?

Comment: I haven't heard of one, could not find one when I looked, and can't see a compelling reason to create one - I have trouble with short answers ;) - "no".

Answer (score 1):

I suggested you using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/). this very popular.

Comment: mongoose is not a mongo client per-se. it is an ORM. it gives abstraction over mongo api. I am looking for a mongo api like library without anything additional.